# Detecting if a Facebook post has been deleted or has high privacy settings

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I want to know with the opengraph FB API if a post is deleted or has high privacy settings. 
If I do a request to a specific post_id that is under one of the two previous parameters the response is ever something like "unsupported get request".

My question: is there a method that can I differentiate if the post exists (and then is under privacy settings) or if the post not exists anymore (deleted)?

Comment: With a user access token of the user that made the post you should be able to read the post. But it sounds like you are trying to award users for making posts (or to punish them for not making those posts visible enough) – which is against the Facebook Platform Policies.

Comment: @CBroe absolutely not. That I want to do is to display in an external site of FB the posts presents in a Page, but having half list of posts empty is not a good thing, if you read the question I don't ask to know who has write the post (only know if post is under privacy or deleted). Please READ CAREFULLY before writing non-sense.

Comment: You did not write _anything_ about what you want to use this for, so I just made an assumption. Anyway, if it’s about a page’s post, just get a page access token and you should get all posts.

Comment: The problem is that I am not the owner of the page, then I get only the public-settings posts (and meanwhile the page can delete some posts).

Comment: Well, that’s what (page) privacy is about, isn’t it? If its not public, then _you_ don’t get to see it without someone giving you permission first.

Comment: I think you haven't good understand the question: there are 2 users, one with high privacy setting and the other not, they posts something on a page (with public access). I get with opengraph the lists of posts (both but only for example # likes on these posts), then the page delete the post "posted" by the public-privacy user. After a while, I ask to the page, with opengraph to have for example the url of the posts on this page, but the response is empty ("unsupported get request") for both (one is deleted and the other is under privacy). How can I know if a post is deleted or under privacy?

Comment: @CBroe what are you basing "you are trying to award users for making posts (or to punish them for not making those posts visible enough) – which is against the Facebook Platform Policies." on? can you tell me what clause does this violates?

Comment: @OfekRon: https://developers.facebook.com/policy#properuse, point 4.5: _“Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions.”_ Click on the question mark next to it, to see more concrete examples.

Comment: @CBroe so it is ok to award users for checking in to places?